# Bicubic Interpolation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

My assignment question is :
"In Lecture 9 Slide No.21 There are Affine Transform based equations. Take an input gray-scale image and apply these transformations one by one. The interpolation used must be bi-cubic."
Now the equations are:
[image]

I am not understanding what exactly is meant by this question? I mean should i just apply transformation on an image or what? I am confused

Comment: Supposedly, you should have learnt something as of now that would tell you how to do this. Or, you can ask your teacher. What this basically is asking is for you to apply matrix transformations to an input image (such as rotating it), and using [bicubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) for that. Bicubic interpolation is to make pixels not look jaggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure your TA could answer here...

Anyway, you have to apply the transformations to a set of coordinates (probably two coordinates per pixel if you want to transform images). Since you will get real values instead of integers (as the pixel grid requires), you have to apply bicubic interpolation to obtain the final values on the destination pixel grid.

Comment: Also, I think the transformations you have to apply to the coordinates are the inverse of the transformation you want. I.e. if you want to enlarge the image, you need to shrink the coordinates when you resample the image.